# jQuery returning [object Object] values (Mirroring values of a text input field)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, input

I have 4 inputs in a single form:
1 - Name
2 - First Name
3 - Last Name
4 - Staff Name (Hidden input)

I need to mirror the values inside **Name** text field onto the **Staff Name** text field everytime the **Name** input is updated/changed. I need the changes to reflect in real time and I'm able to achieve this with my code.

The problem I'm having is: I need to check if **Name** input exists or not, and if not -- to use **First Name** and **Last Name** input values instead.

I'm able to successfully mirror **Name** text values, but during instances when the code has to use **First Name** and **Last Name** values, the values being mirrored show up as: `[object Object]`

I'm completely lost because console.log() shows the correct results.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.fn.existsWithValue = function() { 
        return this.length && this.val().length; 
    }

    var name_field = $('form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="Name"]');

    // Function that mirrors the "Staff Name" and "Name" fields everytime the "Name" field is updated
    // Mirrors "Name", "First Name" or "Last Name" inputs, depending on what input exists...
    $('form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="Name"], form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="First Name"], form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="Last Name"]').bind('keyup change', function(e) {

      if ($(name_field).existsWithValue()) {
        // "Name" input exists, mirror "Name" input value:
        var name_field_final = $('form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="Name"]').val();
      } else {
        // "Name" input does not exist, mirror "First Name" and "Last Name" input values:
        var first_name = $('form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="First Name"]').val();
        var last_name = $('form[name="card_form"] input[placeholder="Last Name"]').val();

        var name_field_final = first_name + ' ' + last_name;
      }

      // MIRROR VALUES in "Staff" input:
      $('form[name="card_form"] input[name="staff"]').attr("value", $(name_field_final));

      // DEBUG
      console.log( first_name + " : " + last_name );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem appears to be caused from setting attribute with an object as value when attributes can only be strings. Also best to set the value property using `val()`

Change

```
 // MIRROR VALUES in "Staff" input:
  $('form[name="card_form"] input[name="staff"]').attr("value", $(name_field_final));
```

to

```
 // MIRROR VALUES in "Staff" input:
  $('form[name="card_form"] input[name="staff"]').val(name_field_final);
```

Answer (score 3):

remove `$` from here it make jQuery object

```
  // MIRROR VALUES in "Staff" input:
  $('form[name="card_form"] input[name="staff"]').val (name_field_final);
```